# Unable to create Android virtual device in Android Studio Setup Wizard

Tags: android

Hy
  i'm trying to install Android Studio , i'm new in it, i have the next problem:  when installing Android Studio in the setup wizard at the end the wizard show me this error:

```
Installing Android SDK Tools, revision 24.0.2
    Installed Android SDK Tools, revision 24.0.2
  Installing Google APIs, Android API 21, revision 1
    Installed Google APIs, Android API 21, revision 1
  Installing Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image, Google Inc. API 21, revision 3
    Installed Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image, Google Inc. API 21, revision 3
    Updated ADB to support the USB devices declared in the SDK add-ons.
  Stopping ADB server failed (code -1).
  Unable to run 'adb': Cannot run program "/home/julio/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb": java.io.IOException: error=2, No existe el archivo o el directorio.
  Starting ADB server failed (code -1).
  Done. 9 packages installed.
Android SDK is up to date.
Creating Android virtual device
Unable to create a virtual device: Unable to create Android virtual device
```

i'm running ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

However the wizard enabled the finish button , and let me create a new project, but i worry that the error in the avd could carry future errors, as i said i'm new in Android . i have done some research in the web but all of the answers are for eclipse.

what could it be?

Comment: If you create a second AVD, and you do not get this error, then everything is fine. It looks like it was installing the Android SDK tools, and **`adb`** is part of those tools. Hence, **`adb`** would not have existed yet to run, resulting in the error message.

Comment: Try this (it worked for me to fix that error)
http://askubuntu.com/questions/560172/cannot-install-android-studio-on-ubuntu-error-unable-to-access-sdk

Answer (score 2):

the comment of @John fix the error:
Try this (it worked for me to fix that error) https://askubuntu.com/questions/560172/cannot-install-android-studio-on-ubuntu-error-unable-to-access-sdk